# How does Swift infer Sequence requirements when Self implements IteratorProtocol?

Tags: swift, types, protocols, sequence, type-inference

I'm reading the Sequence documentation and in an example that they use (see below) the requirements for Sequence are inferred. My question is how is it inferred. I understand how inferencing works in simpler cases but in this example I cannot understand how Swift infers things.

I see that Sequence's makeIterator method has a default implementation but I don't understand how the return value is inferred here.

**Example**

```
struct Countdown: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {

    var count: Int

    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        if count == 0 {
            return nil
        } else {
            defer { count -= 1 }
            return count
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Reference for types mentioned above**

```
IteratorProtocol {

   func next() -> Self.Element?

   associatedtype Iterator

   associatedtype Element
}
```

```
Sequence {

   func makeIterator() -> Self.Iterator

   associatedtype Iterator

   associatedtype Element

}
```

Comment: You seem to have made a copy-paste error in the declaration of `Sequence`.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks I just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the implementation of `IteratorProtocol.next`. The compiler sees this implementation:

```
mutating func next() -> Int? {
    if count == 0 {
        return nil
    } else {
        defer { count -= 1 }
        return count
    }
}
```

And notices that it returns an `Int?`. Well, [`IteratorProtocol.next`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol/1641682-next) is supposed to return a `Self.Element?`, so it infers that `IteratorProtocol.Element == Int`. Now `Coundown` satisfies `IteratorProtocol`.

Note that `Sequence` and `IteratorProtocol` *share* the associated type `Element`. Once Swift figures out the witness for `IteratorProtcol.Element`, it's as if you declared a new type alias `Element` in `Countdown`, and it just so happens that `Sequence` requires that `Countdown.Element` to exist.

After that, the compiler infers `Iterator == Self`. This is so that the default implementation of `makeIterator` is available. However, it is quite a mystery *how* the compiler can infer this, because with only these information, the type can't normally be inferred, as can be shown by creating your own sequence and iterator protocols.

```
protocol MyIterator {
    associatedtype Element
    
    mutating func next() -> Element?
}

protocol MySequence {
    associatedtype Element where Element == Iterator.Element
    associatedtype Iterator : MyIterator
    
    func makeIterator() -> Iterator
}

extension MySequence where Self == Self.Iterator {
    func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        return self
    }
}

struct Countdown: MySequence, MyIterator { // doesn't compile
    var count: Int

    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        if count == 0 {
            return nil
        } else {
            defer { count -= 1 }
            return count
        }
    }
}
```

After looking into the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L385), I suspect there might be some compiler magic going on, especially here:

```
// Provides a default associated type witness for Iterator when the
// Self type is both a Sequence and an Iterator.
extension Sequence where Self: IteratorProtocol {
  // @_implements(Sequence, Iterator)
  public typealias _Default_Iterator = Self
}
```

This seems to set a "preferred" type for `Iterator` to be inferred as. It seems to be saying "When `Iterator` can't be inferred to be anything, try `Self`". I can't find `_Default_Iterator` anywhere else, which is why I concluded it's compiler magic. The whole purpose of this is to allow you to conform to `Sequence` by only conforming to `IteratorProtocol` and implementing `next`, as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence#2849767) said you can do.

Now that `Iterator == Self`, we have also satisfied the constraint on `Element`:

```
associatedtype Element where Self.Element == Self.Iterator.Element
```

Thus we have shown that `Countdown` conforms to `Sequence`.

Comment: I may have figured it out. If we implement Sequence we would set: typealias Iterator as Self because CountDown is an Iterator and Swift can infer that Self is being its own iterator. Although, you have a good point about the compiler magic thing going on. As you pointed out also, maybe you can rephrase your answer to highlight the point that the compiler infers it because it knows that self is an iterator. Ill mark it as correct

Comment: @3366784 I'm not sure what you mean, but I have tried my best and edited anyway. Feel free to suggest an edit yourself :)